# How to get std::chrono::time_point clock type

Tags: c++

I have a class with a std::chrono::time_point member. In one of the class functions I want to create another time_point with the same clock type.

How do I take the clock type from my member?

I tried doing:

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> m_time_point;
std::chrono::time_point<m_time_point.clock> new_tp(some_duration)
```

but this results with an
 error: cannot refer to type member 'clock' in 'std::chrono::time_point' with '.'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::chrono::time_point` is a template, not a type. So you can't have a member with this type, it has to be instantiated with some type of the clock. Assuming you have it, and you member name is `m_time_point`, getting to clock is trivial:

```
using clock_t = decltype(m_time_point)::clock;
```